# Elastic Beanstalk: allow user to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I can't figure out how to let other people in my company deploy to a (test) server with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

This page suggests only global permission control over the ELB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html

Comment: do you want to restrict it to specific beanstalk applications?

Comment: Yes, to a specific application and specific environment. Can't find how to.

Comment: Somebody seems to have shared it already on github. https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/5034bdbb049181a96ac9

Comment: Looks promising, thank you. Will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rhys Godfrey blog post titled [Using IAM to secure Elastic Beanstalk Applications on AWS](https://www.rhysgodfrey.co.uk/b/blog/posts/using-iam-to-secure-elastic-beanstalk-applications-on-aws) has some good guidance.

> We have an Elastic Beanstalk application, and a group of users. This
>   group of users should be able to monitor and deploy to only that
>   elastic beanstalk environment, as well as restarting or terminating
>   application instance. They should not be able to change the
>   application or environments configuration, or delete the environment.
>   The user should not be able to affect other applications or AWS
>   services, but it is acceptable for them to see details on other areas.
>   We assume the user will be using the AWS console.

I have reposted the IAM policies here for reference.

The nice thing about his approach is that it considers the application environment by referencing an EC2 tag on the instances EG `Environment=testing`, which you require in your use case.

```
{  
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Sid":"ElasticBeanstalkEnvironmentPermissions",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentResources",
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
            "elasticbeanstalk:RestartAppServer",
            "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
            "elasticbeanstalk:SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs",
            "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
            "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1:123xxxxxxxxx:environment/ApplicationName/*"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"ElasticBeanstalkGlobalPermissions",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationSettings",
            "elasticbeanstalk:ListAvailableSolutionStacks",
            "elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings",
            "elasticbeanstalk:CheckDNSAvailability",
            "elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "*"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"ElasticBeanstalkApplicationVersionPermissions",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplicationVersions",
            "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplicationVersion"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1:123xxxxxxxxx:applicationversion/ApplicationName/*"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"ElasticBeanstalkApplicationPermissions",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications",
            "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplication"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1:123xxxxxxxxx:application/ApplicationName"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"Autoscaling",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
            "autoscaling:Describe*",
            "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"Cloudwatch",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "cloudwatch:Describe*",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "cloudwatch:ListMetrics"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"Cloudformation",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
            "cloudformation:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"IAM",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "iam:ListServerCertificates",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"S3ElasticBeanstalkBucket",
         "Action":[  
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketCORS",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetBucketLogging",
            "s3:GetBucketNotification",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
            "s3:GetBucketTagging",
            "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
            "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
            "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-123xxxxxxxxx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-123xxxxxxxxx/*"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"S3Global",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"S3ElasticBeanstalkShared",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"s3:*",
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-eu-west-1",
            "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-eu-west-1/*"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Sid":"EC2Global",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "ec2:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The second IAM policy handles EC2 instances for a given environment:

```
{  
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Sid":"EC2EnvironmentInstances",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "ec2:MonitorInstances",
            "ec2:UnmonitorInstances",
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123xxxxxxxxx:instance/*"
         ],
         "Condition":{  
            "StringEquals":{  
               "ec2:ResourceTag/elasticbeanstalk:environment-name":"EnvironmentName"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```